# Getting Sum of rows and putting back the result to the rows as a separate column

Tags: sql, group-by

Im currently facing with a challenge of getting sum for rows grouping them by specific fields and then putting the result back to each individual row.

The group by that i want to do is Client & Group & Year and get the sums for Amount and Months.

Heres an example of the data set and the 2 right columns are ones that i want to add:

```
Client   Group    Year         Amount   Months     Sum(Amount)   Sum(Months)

Client1  Group1   Current Year    100       3             300           10
Client1  Group1   Current Year    200       7             300           10
Client2  Group1   Year-1          150       1             400           3
Client2  Group1   Year-1          250       2             400           3
Client3  Group1   Year-2          500       11            500           11
Client3  Group2   Year-3          600       12            600           12
```

The code that i have currently is structured as follows:

```
Select 
  Data.Client, data.Group, Calc_field2.Year, data.Amount, Calc_field.Months

From
  (Select [Column adjustments] From [Source] where [criteria]
   Union ALL 
   Select * from [Source#2] where [Criteria]
   ) as Data

Cross Apply
  (Data.[End Date] - Data.[Start Date]) as Calc_Field(Months)
 [Rolling Year formula from Data] as Calc_Field2(Year)
```

Thus was thinking to add a cross apply:

```
Cross Apply
(Select
    Data.Client, Data.Group, Calc_field2.Year,
    SUM(Data.Amount) as 'SUM Amount',
    SUM(Calc_Field.Months) as 'SUM Months'
 Group by
    Data.Client, Data.Group, Calc_field2.Year
 ) as MONTH_AMOUNT_SUM
```

And then add it to the main part as

```
MONTH_AMOUNT_SUM.[SUM Month], MONTH_AMOUNT_SUM.[SUM Amount]
```

I had a feeling it wouldnt work, which was confirmed by:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Would anyone have any suggestions of best way to approach this?

Thank you,
Lukas

Comment: Which RDMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions.  The only part of the query that changes is the `select`:

```
select Data.Client, data.Group, Calc_field2.Year, data.Amount, Calc_field.Months,
       sum(data.amount) over (partition by data.client, data.group, calc_field2.year),
       sum(data.months) over (partition by data.client, data.group, calc_field2.year)
```

Comment: That is perfect and very efficient, wasnt aware of such option. Thank you!